# Silverlight Datagrid Row Click

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a column containing a checkbox. I want to change the value of the bound Selected property when the row is clicked:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw6YtzRWGEI/AAAAAAAAGlQ/pntIr2GU6Mo/image_thumb%5B3%5D.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw6YtzRWGEI/AAAAAAAAGlQ/pntIr2GU6Mo/image_thumb%5B3%5D.png)

NOTE: I don't want to use the SelectedItemChanged event because this doesn't work properly when there is only one row in the grid.

Comment: Do you want to toggle when the row is clicked again?  Is there anywhere on the row where clicking should not have this effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is often the way i have found my own solution for this:

Add a MouseLeftButtonUp event to the datagrid:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgTaskLinks"
ItemsSource="{Binding TaskLinks}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTaskLink, Mode=TwoWay}"
MouseLeftButtonUp="dgTaskLinks_MouseLeftButtonUp"
>...
```

And [walk the visual tree](http://thoughtjelly.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/walking-the-xaml-visualtree-to-find-a-parent-of-type-t/) to get the data grid row:

```
private void dgTaskLinks_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                ///get the clicked row
                DataGridRow row = MyDependencyObjectHelper.FindParentOfType<DataGridRow>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

                ///get the data object of the row
                if (row != null && row.DataContext is TaskLink) 
                {
                    ///toggle the IsSelected value
                    (row.DataContext as TaskLink).IsSelected = !(row.DataContext as TaskLink).IsSelected;
                }

            }
```

Once found, it is a simple approach to toggle the bound IsSelected property :-)

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I like your solution. It makes a little more sense than mine. Although, I'm wondering where you got this 'MyDependencyObjectHelper' class from. I assume its your custom code. Care to share it?

Comment: It's linked in the the answer under "Walk the visual tree". GLad this helped, Mark

Comment: +1 Great solution! I spent 3 hours trying to hack a grid to "auto select" a check box and didn't come up with anything nearly as elegant.

Comment: @MarkCooper I'm getting a permission denied message from Blogger when I try to access the "walk the visual tree" link. Could you change it to be open access, or put the code here in your answer?

Comment: @flipchart blog was moved to wordpress. Link has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even simpler solution

XAML

```
<data:DataGrid 
x:Name="dgMyDataGrid" 
ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
SelectedItem="{Binding MyList, Mode=TwoWay}"
 MouseLeftButtonUp="dgMyDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp">...
```

CS

```
private void dgMyDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = (sender as DataGrid);
    var allObjects = dg.DataContext as List<MyCustomObject>;
    foreach(var o in allObjects)
    {
          o.Selected = false;
    }

    MyCustomObject SelectedObject = (MyCustomObject)dg.SelectedItem;
    SelectedObject.Selected = true;
}
```

Note: this as well as the other example assumes your class that you are binding to the control implements INotifyPropertyChanged